# Memory efficient slicing numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, memory, slice

I am using the following line of code to slice a 7.4GB array:

```
xTrain = cp.array(db[(db[:,0]>=trainStartDate)&(db[:,0]<=trainEndDate)][:,5:])
```

I don't understand why I run out of RAM, I have 25GB. That would mean at least 3 copies of the array get made in that one line. Is that correct? Is there a better way of slicing like this?

Comment: Please make sure that this problem is reproducible by giving all relevant information including the shape of db. And did you mean `np.array`?